# Magento2: Add JS from Admin CMS page Design "layout update XML"

Tags: layout, magento2.1.6, cms-pages

I did added JS file from design layout update from Admin CMS page- > Design
layout update XML ,  but it showing jQuery is not defined error, When I view source , these files are being added before the requireJS file.

How to add JS from  Admin->Content->Pages ->Open CMS page -> Design ->"layout update XML" ?

```
<head> 
 <script src="js/pi.googleMapStyles.js" order="100"/>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" src_type="url" order="101"/>
<script src="js/jquery.gmap.min.js" order="102"/>
<script src="js/pi.global.js" order="103"/><script src="js/pi.init.map.js" order="104"/>
</head>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must quit what you have done so far in the XML layout.

You need `requirejs-config.js` in this path `app/design/frontend/VendorName/Theme/` with bellow content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom_js: 'VendorName_Theme/js/js_file_name'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        custom_js: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

**OR**

You need `requirejs-config.js` in this path `/app/design/frontend/VendorName/Theme/web/js/` with bellow content:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom_js: 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/js_file_name'
        }
    }
};
```

In a template you can call it:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'custom_js'
    ], function ($, script) {
        //Your code here
        //alert('Here');
    });
</script>
```

**OR**

In a template you can call it:

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'VendorName_ModuleName/js/js_file_name'
    ], function ($, script) {
        //Your code here
        //alert('Here');
    });
</script>
```

---

You can add for any CMS Pages (from admin) a template file in `Layout Update XML`

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

You can add for a test in `test.phtml` file from `Magento_Theme` in your current theme:

```
<pre>11111111</pre>
<script>
  require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Theme/js/js_file_name'
  ], function ($, script) {
    //Your code here
    alert('js_file_name - test');
  });
</script>
```

You can add for a test in `js_file_name.js` file from `Magento_Theme` in your current theme:

```
console.log(1234567890987654321);
```

After seeing your test work, you can change how you want it.

Comment: What in case if we just want to add this JS files into one cms page only ?

Comment: If you want to add in one page, then you can use one of the last two examples above in a file template, and that file is loaded only there.

Comment: I need to add on cms page and tempalte for cms is common for all cms page , so just to be clear when you say file template, I can add this code into CMS page from admin and it should work fine , correct ?

Comment: You did not specify this in your description.
You can only add a template file for cms pages `<referenceContainer name="content">
   <referenceBlock name="cms_page">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test.trigger" template="test.phtml"/>
   </referenceBlock>
  </referenceContainer>`.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion , I thought I added in my question title

Comment: In this case it will apply to all cms pages ,where as I just need for only one cms page and so  I need to use the design layout update under CMS page from admin , hope that make clear now

Comment: I'll try to help you.

Comment: I think only through a module can do this.

Comment: Please check at the end of my answer, there I put how you can do what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64658/discussion-between-st3phan-and-pravin).

Comment: Hey, [Pravin](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/2327/pravin) My answer helped you?

Comment: Yes , It works fine

Comment: hey St3phan, i am trying to add some js code to cms form i.e cms_page_form but this is not loaded initially. How to trace that and get this done? any idea?

Comment: Hey, please put the js code here and today I help you.