# Magento 2 : Add custom js to a single CMS page

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, cms-pages

I am trying to add **`custom js`** to a single **`CMS page`** in **Magento 2.2.5**.

Here is what I got:

I have put the **`rellax.min.js`** file at :`/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md/web/js`

And I want to use that **js** on my `about us` **CMS page** so I invoked it like :

```
<script src="/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md/web/js/rellax.min.js" type="text/javascript" xml="space"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
  var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
// ]]></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="rellax slide1"></div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">some text</div>
<div class="rellax slide2"></div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">some text</div>
<div class="rellax slide3"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I am facing is that the **js** doesn't seem to affect the `rellax` class like it is suppose to do.

Thanks for the help.

I have added `rellax.js` in `/public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md/web/js`
Then `requirejs-config.js` in this path 
`/public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md` with the following code

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            rellax: 'md/js/rellax'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        rellax: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
};
```

And this is the code in my CMS page

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">// <![CDATA[
    require([
        'jquery',
        'md/js/rellax'
    ], function ($, script) {
        var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
        alert('Here');
    });
// ]]></script>
<div class="content">
<div class="rellax slide1"></div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">some text</div>
<div class="rellax slide2"></div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">some text</div>
<div class="rellax slide3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check edit

Comment: The page is still showing the same thing with the same errors on the rellax.js script.

Comment: Please post the errors

Comment: Please run deploy commands, and fix permissions. Also make sure you are calling js just the way listed in the answer and no other way.

Comment: I have done both and still the same errors for the rellax.js script

Comment: I think you must have deleted .htaccess located  pub/static , if you've renamed the files please restore it and it should work

Comment: .htaccess is there and the files are named correctly sorry

Comment: I have put this in my .phtml document instead.
`<div class="content">
<div class="rellax slide1"></div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">some text</div>
<div class="rellax slide2"></div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">some text</div>
<div class="rellax slide3"></div>
</div>

<script src="/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md/web/js/rellax.js"></script>
<script>
  var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
</script>`
There is no longer an error and it reads the .rellax script but without any effect on my `.rellax` class

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by two ways as described below.

First create the custom.js at below location (in your case you have already did this)

> app/design/{Vendor_name}/{theme}/web/js/custom.js

Now you can choose any of the below steps for your requirement.

**1st Way**

Just traverse to the below location

> Admin > Content > Elements > Pages > Design > Layout Update XML

Put the below code there in that section

```
<head>
    <link src="js/custom.js"/>
</head>
```

Save the page & flush the cache & you will see it is working

**2nd Way**

Just traverse to the below location

> Admin > Content > Elements > Pages > Content

Put the below code there in that section

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"}}
```

Now traverse to the below location & create a file with name **`test.phtml`**

> Magento_root/app/design/frontend/{Vendor_name}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/templates/test.phtml

Put the below code there

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
      ".Your_class/#Your_id": {
              "https://www.example.com/demo/pub/static/frontend/{Vendor_name}/{theme}/en_US/js/custom.js": {}
       }
}
</script>
```

Now again flush the cache & refresh the page you will see your changes are working

> Note: If it is not rendering your **js** there just do run the
>   following commands from your magento_root
>
> ```
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

Comment: You are always welcome on MSE @GabrielLemire

Answer (score 4):

In magento 2 require js is used for sorting dependencies between js and loading them accordingly, so I suggest you use the same for doing it in your cms page.

A related question  has been asked before too so I am just going to reference great answer given by @St3phan   [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190821/magento2-add-js-from-admin-cms-page-design-layout-update-xml) -

> You must quit what you have done so far in the XML layout.
>
> You need `requirejs-config.js` in this path
>   `app/design/frontend/VendorName/Theme/` with bellow content:
>
> ```
> var config = {
>     map: {
>         '*': {
>             custom_js: 'VendorName_Theme/js/js_file_name'
>         }
>     },
>     shim: {
>         custom_js: {
>             deps: ['jquery']
>         },
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> **OR**
>
> You need `requirejs-config.js` in this path
>   `/app/design/frontend/VendorName/Theme/web/js/` with bellow content:
>
> ```
> var config = {
>     map: {
>         '*': {
>             custom_js: 'VendorName_ModuleName/js/js_file_name'
>         }
>     }
> }; In a template you can call it:
>
> <script>
>     require([
>         'jquery',
>         'custom_js'
>     ], function ($, script) {
>         //Your code here
>         //alert('Here');
>     });
> </script> <br/>
> ```
>
> **OR**
>
> In a template you can call it:
>
> ```
> <script>
>     require([
>         'jquery',
>         'VendorName_ModuleName/js/js_file_name'
>     ], function ($, script) {
>         //Your code here
>         //alert('Here');
>     });
> </script> <br/> <hr/> <br/> You can add for any CMS Pages (from admin) a template file in `Layout Update XML`
>
> <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
>     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"/>
> </referenceContainer>
> ```
>
> You can add for a test in `test.phtml` file from `Magento_Theme` in
>   your current theme:
>
> ```
> <pre>11111111</pre>
> <script>
>   require([
>     'jquery',
>     'Magento_Theme/js/js_file_name'
>   ], function ($, script) {
>     //Your code here
>     alert('js_file_name - test');
>   });
> </script>
> ```
>
> You can add for a test in `js_file_name.js` file from
>   `Magento_Theme` in your current theme:
>
> ```
> console.log(1234567890987654321); <br/> After seeing your test work, you can change how you want it.
> ```

**EDIT :**

Just make a new phtml in Magento/Theme/templates folder of your theme and reference in layout update like following ;

```
<referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Magento_Theme::test.phtml"/>
     </referenceContainer>
```

Then in  the  phtml paste all the code you've done in your cms page and it should work fine.

Feel free to ask in case of any confusion

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried all the different methods explained by st3phan without any success. What information would you need to further help me.

Comment: Is rellax.min.js loading in your page?

Comment: It is loading with those errors:
Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/TemplateMonster/md/en_CA/md/js/rellax.js'
#0 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/StaticResource.php(134): Magento\Framework\View\Asset\File->getSourceFile()
#1 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource->launch()
#2 /public_html/pub/static.php(13): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\StaticResource))
#3 {main}

Comment: I have added `rellax.js` in `/public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md/web/js`
Then `requirejs-config.js` in this path 
`/public_html/app/design/frontend/TemplateMonster/md` with the following code `var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            rellax: 'md/js/rellax'
        }
    },
    shim: {
        rellax: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
    }
}; `

Comment: Magento's way of serving files is a bit more complex then just stating paths ..
Please may want to read up about magento's pipeline deployment  here -  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/deployment/

Comment: I have edited my question if you wanna take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add inside of the content. It will work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" xml="space">
// <![CDATA[
require([ "jquery" ], function( $ ) {
 console.log('working...');
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

Thanks, thumps up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ManiMaran!! This is indeed the secret for getting more complex javascript to work inside Magento 2.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'],function($) {
       //YOUR LOVELY JAVASCRIPT GOES HERE AND WILL NOW WORK IN CMS PAGE
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a simple one that will work on a **block/page** and **.phtml** template also.
Here **Rafiqul_Blog** is the Vendor_Module and **js** is the js folder and **test** is the test.js file

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Rafiqul_Blog/js/test" : {}
        }
    }
</script>
```